# How to mock a computed property in Vue 3 unit test?

Tags: vue.js, unit-testing, migration, vuejs3, vue-test-utils

I want to migrate jest unit tests from `vue 2` to `vue 3`. But I'm stuck with mocking up `computed` props.

I got a lot of vue-2 unit tests written like this:

```js
const wrapper = shallowMount(FooComponent, {
  computed: {
    myComputedProp: () => false // The intention is to return "false" during unit tests no matter what
  }
});
```

That was working in vue 2 world, but seems has no effect after the migration to vue 3 and the compatible vue-test utils.

Some of the components atm on composition api, while the others yet on options api.

I'd prefer to not re-write all these unit tests, cause it's a migration, but find a way to mock computed props once again if that's possible.

Thanks

Comment: This is likely XY problem. You're unable to fully mock a computed or other properties with composition in a reasonable way, you'll end up mocking `vue` import and fragile tests. You have to treat a component as a grey box

Comment: As far as I know, that is not possible anymore within Vue 3 and the compatible test utils. As computed properties are always derived from some state in the component, you need to make sure to either mock the state or the composable, that generates the state. You could also try to use `wrapper.vm.$options.computed` inside your test and set the function there. I don't know if this works.

Comment: It would be `wrapper.vm.$options.computed.myComputedProp = () => false`